# For some reason my player doesn't teleport when I want it to?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game I want to make it so that when the player touches lava it takes 10 damage and moves 200 meters in the air. My problem is that he doesn't move. I don't have that much knowledge about this but I did what I though would work but for some reason it doesn't. I know that it happens because the player takes damage. So the problem is with the code. The only part that should be relevant is the code at the bottom in HitLava. I included the other code just in case you wanted it. Thanks!

My code: (Sorry if it is bad I am a programming noob)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class Healths : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float healthPoints = 100.0f;
    private Coroutine onHit = null;
    private Coroutine onHitLava = null;
    private Coroutine onHeal = null;
    public GameObject Player;
    private float xpos;
    private float zpos;
    private float ypos;
        

    private void Update()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Updaate());

        if (onHeal == null)
            onHeal = StartCoroutine(HealthRegen());

        
    }

    IEnumerator Updaate()
    {
        if (healthPoints <= 0)
        {
            // SceneManager.LoadScene("Game_Over"); change to go to checkpoint
        }

        if (healthPoints >= 101.0f)
        {
            healthPoints = 100.0f;
        }   

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Zombie")
        {
            if (onHit == null)
                onHit = StartCoroutine(HitDelay());
        }

        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Lava")
        {
            if (onHitLava == null)
                onHitLava = StartCoroutine(HitLava());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator HitDelay()
    {
        healthPoints = healthPoints - 15;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
        onHit = null;
    }

    IEnumerator HealthRegen()
    {
        healthPoints = healthPoints + 1;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        onHeal = null;
    }

    IEnumerator HitLava()
    {
        healthPoints = healthPoints - 10;
        zpos = Player.transform.position.z;
        xpos = Player.transform.position.x;
        ypos = Player.transform.position.y + 200;
        Player.transform.position = new Vector3(xpos, ypos, zpos);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        onHit = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just in general you could shrink that to simply `Player.transform.position += Vector3.up * 200;` which would it make way shorter and easier to understand and maintain ;) .. are sure the routine gets executed? Can you see the health be decreased? Is anything else maybe overwriting the position?

Comment: @derHugo Yeah I can see health be decreased (I have a healthbar)

Comment: @derHugo I tried it but it still didn't work

Comment: How are you moving your player?

Comment: I am using the FPS controller from unity standard assets

Comment: What is happening. Is the player not teleporting, or is it going to high?

Comment: It is just not moving at all ( neither )

Comment: Does it take damage? If it doesn’t, put a print statement in the if statement that calls the coroutine. Then, check if anything gets printed. If it doesn’t, you know the problem is with the if statement.

Comment: The player object doesn't teleport at all, not even once? If the answer is yes, are you sure that the `if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Lava")` results in `true` when you touch the lava? If the answer is no and the player object does get teleported ones, but then stops it might be because of the `if (onHitLava == null)`, in your code `onHitLava` is getting set to a coroutine but is never set back to `null`.

Comment: @ken OP already stated that the health is decreased as expected though ;)

Comment: @Space see comment before

Comment: @AryaAkhavein are you sure your Lava is tagged as lava an not maybe as zombie? ^^

Comment: @derHugo all he said was that he sees his health decrease, didn't specify from what `HitDelay` or `HitLava`, it could just be decreasing from `HitDelay` but not from `HitLava` cuz it's never executed, that's something else he didn't answer, if `HitLava` actually is getting executed

Comment: @derHugo (1) I tested it like you said and it did print (2)  and I know it is tagged as lava

Comment: @ken it's not a problem .. in this case it only assures that you don't get hit each frame but rather in certain time intervals

Comment: @AryaAkhavein I think the fact that `onHitLava` is never set back to null is the issue, if you have a look at the code in `HitDelay` he has `onHit = null;` because `onHit = HitDelay` and in `HealthRegen` they have `onHeal = null;` because `onHeal = HealthRegen` but in `HitLava` they have `onHit = null;` even tho it should be `onHitLava = null;`

Comment: @AryaAkhavein what scripts to do you have that are changing the player’s transform? Is it just this one and your movement script? Are you using Rigidbody or CharacterController?

Comment: @ken I am using a rigidbody and a charatercontroller

Comment: Use one or the other. Using both usually causes problems.

Comment: The `CharacterController` (which assume you are referring to) is **physics based** .. it is possible that this causes an issue .. try using the `characterController.Move` instead of directly going through the `Transform` component

Comment: I recommend using CharacterController, and using Brackey’s tutorial on it. [first person version](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj07JW08_7wAhVrAp0JHXS5AMQQwqsBMAB6BAgHEAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D_QajrabyTJc&usg=AOvVaw01TTqqownZn-dK7MvefvNy) and [3rd person version](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj07JW08_7wAhVrAp0JHXS5AMQQwqsBMAF6BAgIEAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D4HpC--2iowE&usg=AOvVaw0laE-543s_NiR44IMEHCx6)

Comment: @derHugo sorry but how would I implement characterController.Move?

Comment: @AryaAkhavein you would use this in `HitLava()`: `CharacterController cc = Player.GetComponent<CharacterController>(); ... cc.Move(Vector3.up * 200);`

Comment: @ken TYSM I have been trying to figure this out forever

Comment: Most likely you don't have the correct tags set. Because your code is fine